# Loading VS project fails with InvalidProjectDataException

Tags: path, properties, visual-studio-2022, target

I'm having a problem loading a sample project in VS 2022 Enterprise
I 'm missing a target Path property (is empty) but can not find where to set it.
Since project not loads, I guess I need to set it manually as a text path in either .sln or .csproj file?
Error message is:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.ProjectSystem.InvalidProjectDataException: Property 'TargetPath' is required to be an absolute path, but the value is ''.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.ProjectSystem.EvaluationData.GetRequiredPropertyAbsolutePathValue(String name)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.CPS.CPSProjectFactory.d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.LanguageServices.Workspace.<>c__DisplayClass39_0.<g__ProcessInitialEvaluationDataAsync|1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.g__Action|0()
at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by closing VS 2022, then deleting the `.vs` folder in the solution root folder, and opening the solution again. Hope this helps.